# First drop down menu to auto change the options of a second dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have two drop down menus where the options are not get from the database.

The first one, lets the user to select a category.

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

The options of the second, are depended from the choice in the first dropdown menu. For example, if the user chooses the **First** option then the second dropdown will show

```
<select name="items">
    <option value="3">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8">Charger</option>
</select>
```

but when the user change his mind, or select the **second** option first, then the second dropdown will now show

```
<select name="items">
    <option value="1">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4">Volleyball</option>
</select>
```

My question is how can I achieve this ? Can this be done without using a database?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are the values for the items drop down coming from?

Comment: Sure you can ..use Ajax for that

Comment: For the database, you can see my answer. I have explained on how I have done it. :)

Comment: Added the no database version too! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See below to see the **Working Example without using a Database**.

### Working Example Using MySQL Database

If you wanna connect it using Database, yeah, it is surely possible. Consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `contents` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR (255),
    `parent` INT DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO `contents` (`name`, `parent`) VALUES
    ('Names', 0),
    ('Places', 0),
    ('Animals', 0),
    ('Praveen', 1),
    ('Bill Gates', 1),
    ('Steve Jobs', 1),
    ('India', 2),
    ('New York', 2),
    ('London', 2),
    ('Singapore', 2),
    ('Cat', 3),
    ('Dog', 3),
    ('Tiger', 3),
    ('Deer', 3)
```

### Table Structure

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | name       | parent |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | Names      |      0 |
|  2 | Places     |      0 |
|  3 | Animals    |      0 |
|  4 | Praveen    |      1 |
|  5 | Bill Gates |      1 |
|  6 | Steve Jobs |      1 |
|  7 | India      |      2 |
|  8 | New York   |      2 |
|  9 | London     |      2 |
| 10 | Singapore  |      2 |
| 11 | Cat        |      3 |
| 12 | Dog        |      3 |
| 13 | Tiger      |      3 |
| 14 | Deer       |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

### Initial HTML & PHP Code

Now, lets use PHP to first populate the initial `<select>`:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect();
    mysql_select_db("contents");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = 0");
    while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
        echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>
```

Now the `<select>` is ready. With its onchange function, we can fire an AJAX event to get the new `<select>` with the data provided by the parent `<select>`.

```
<select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
    <!-- Options would have been initially populated here -->
</select>
```

Now for the jQuery function, you can do this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxfunction(parent)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php?parent=' + parent;
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the HTML, after the `<select>`, you need to give another `select` with an `id` as `sub`.

```
<select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
    <!-- Options would have been initially populated here -->
</select>
<select id="sub"></select>
```

### Processing PHP Source Code

Finally the source code of `process.php`:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect();
    mysql_select_db("contents");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["parent"]));
    while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
        echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>
```

### Working Example without using a Database

You just need to replace this in the PHP.

```
<?php
    $parent = array("Name", "Place", "Animals");
    foreach ($parent as $id => $name)
        echo '<option value="s', $id,'">', $name,'</option>'
?>
```

And for the `process.php`:

```
<?php
    $parent = array("Name", "Place", "Animals");
    $s0 = array("Praveen", "Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs");
    foreach (${$_GET["parent"]} as $id => $name)
        echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>
```

Comment: Really handy for a mysql version. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaoukkos Thanks, I have included the database less version too!!! Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I'm trying to use this, as it seems to solve my question as well. What is `$data` defined as, in the non-database example?

Comment: It should be: `'<option value="', $id,'">', $name,'</option>'`

Comment: It also looks like you're sending an array to the process.php file. Is that correct?

Comment: I tried to replicate this, without sending an array, but got some weird 404 error. I asked the question over here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/355330-using-one-dropdown-menu-to-determine-the-options-in-another/

Comment: Thanks for your persistent response! By the way, I figured it out; /* I was trying to access a PHP file in a remote directory, and to remedy that, I got the absolutePath first. See my DreamInCode question. */

Answer (score 5):

The part about the database isn't really clear, since the selects would presumably be "listed" in some fashion. If you have them in some other format, that makes sense, or if you're asking if a call back to the database (`postback`) is necessary, the answer is no. But it's not clear what you mean.

Anyhow, you could use a `rel=""` value (or `data-items=""`) to set the relationship between the one select to the other.

For example:

**CSS**

```
.cascade {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML - Modified**

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1" rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
    <option value="2" rel="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="3" rel="cars">Cars</option>
</select>
<select name="items" class="cascade">
    <option value="3" class="accessories">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8" class="accessories">Charger</option>
    <option value="1" class="sports">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4" class="sports">Volleyball</option>
    <option value="6" class="cars">Corvette</option>
    <option value="2" class="cars">Monte Carloe</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $cat = $('select[name=category]'),
        $items = $('select[name=items]');

    $cat.change(function(){
        var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
            rel = $this.attr('rel'),
            $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);

        if ($set.size() < 0) {
            $items.hide();
            return;
        }

        $items.show().find('option').hide();

        $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bY5LF/

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example, basically all the data is on the page in an object and you use it to display the different catagories  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CxYMB/)

```
var categories = {
    "None":[{value:'3', text:'No cataegory selected'}],
    "First":[{value:'1', text:'Bmw'},{value:'2', text:'Benz'}],
    "Second":[{value:'4', text:'Playstation'},{value:'5', text:'Xbox'},{value:'10', text:'Wii'}],
    "Third":[{value:'6', text:'Dell'},{value:'7', text:'Acer'}],
    "Fourth":[{value:'8', text:'Audi'},{value:'9', text:'Datsun'}]
};
function selectchange(){
    var select = $('[name=items]');
    select.empty();
    $.each(categories[$(':selected', this).text()], function(){
        select.append('<option value="'+this.value+'">'+this.text+'</option>');
    });
}
$(function(){
    $('[name=category]').on('change', selectchange);
});
```

Comment: @Kaoukkos Yes this is good.. Kindly see my answer too, you may use my technique also.

Answer (score 1):

**2 Working Demo for your code** `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/2/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/

It is achievable but you need to make a relationship between first and second select.

Please take a look in here as well: http://api.jquery.com/data/

I have added `label` for relationship here http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/2/ [ http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp ]

**Behaviour** When you will select `first` option from select1 then it will show `smartphone, chargers` otherwise when user will select `second` from select1 it will show `baskeball, voleyball` in select2.

Hope this helps, Please let me know if I missed anything.

**Demo 1**

**Code**

```
$("#category").change(function() {
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    }
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[label=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
   // alert(options);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="select1" id="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<select name="items" id="select2">

    <option value="3" label="1">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8" label="1">Charger</option>

    <option value="1" label="2">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4" label="2">Volleyball</option>
</select>
```

**DEMO 2**
**code**

```
$("#category").change(function() {
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    }
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
    alert(options);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="select1" id="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<select name="items" id="select2">

    <option value="1">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="1">Charger</option>

    <option value="2">Basketball</option>
    <option value="2">Volleyball</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Regarding your first link http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/2/ How should I list the names instead of the label numbers?

Comment: I am asking about the first example because the unique values of the second dropdown menu are needed.

Comment: Hiya, @Kaoukkos howz life? `:)` yes you can, flick me a demo if it doesn't work, **further** so with regards to first demo the mapping is between 1st select1 `id` to `label` of the second select. Indeed you can do the name mapping between the id and the select2 names. let me know if I missed anything, hope this helps, `:)`

Comment: Everything is good. I hope the same for you too. What I mean specifically is the fact that when I choose for example First form the first dropdown I get the number of the labels and not the names of the options.

Comment: @Kaoukkos Hey Cooleos man, Ah do you mean instead of `id` you want to your `name` attribute? `:)` just change the select to `$("select[name=whatevername]")` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PnSCL/8/ `:P`

Answer (score 1):

**Working solution without using any Database:**

**HTML**

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="showState();">   
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="2">Saudi Arabia</option>
</select>

<div id="div_state"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    function showState()
    {
        $('body').css('cursor','wait');
        var value = document.getElementById('country').value;
        var url = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/rathoreahsan/WcKQ2/4/show/';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data:{'country':value},
            success:function(results)
            {              

                $('#div_state').html(results);

                if (value == "1") 
                {
                    $('#PK').css('display','block')                
                } 

                else if (value == "2") 
                {
                    $('#SA').css('display','block')                        
                }

                $('body').css('cursor','default');            

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#PK, #SA { display: none; }
```

**SEE DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/WyLsh/

**States Page:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/rathoreahsan/WcKQ2/4/show/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a very simple full example :**

The external URL will send us the list of option and then we will assign that drop down list to the second drop down menu using jquery $(selector).html() method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#country").on('change',function(){
        var country= $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'cities.php' ,
            type: 'POST',
            data: "country="+country,
            success: function(cities)
            {
                $("#cities").html(cities);
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Full Demo**](https://codingpk.com/Post/Tutorial/how-to-get-drop-down-menu-list-depend-on-changing-the-other-drop-down-list)

Answer (score -1):

Just suggesting how you can do it --

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="showState();" >
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">Nepal</option>
</select>
```

Your Script--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showState( )
{
var value = document.getElementById('country').value;
var url = '<?php echo base_url ?>showstate.php';
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
data:{'country':value},
success:function(results)
{   
    $('#div_state').html(results);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Your `showstate.php` php page --

```
//INCLUDE CONNECTION file to for db query
$type = $_GET['country'];

//Your DB QUERIES
//Your data on Get condition
/*USING SWITCH--
switch ($type) {
case "India":
    echo "I m in India";
    break;
case "Nepal":
    echo "I am in Nepal";
    break;
```

This will load the content in your `#div_state` div. You can also use Jquery For this..i think this will help you :) an d let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @Sibu did you read my code --> "showstate.php" //Your DB QUERIES
//Your data on Get condition if he wants to run db queries he can and if he want to simply use data he can write switch conditions on the basis of his requirement.

Comment: @swapnesh Please let me know how to use the switch conditions in the showstate.php file

Comment: @Kaoukkos np...let me write what u need :)

Comment: @Kaoukkos i edited my answer plz have a look at it ..on showstate.php-edited region ..use default case too

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#causes').change(function(){

         $.getJSON("<?=URL.$param->module."/".$param->controller?>/getcourtcauses",{causeId:  $(this).val()}, function(j){ 

        var options = '';
        if(j.length > 1 )
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
            if($('#subcauses').hide())
                {
                    $('#subcauses').show();
                }
                $('#subcauses').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#subcauses").html("");
            $("#subcauses").html(options);
         }
        else
            {
                $('#subcauses')
                    .find('option')
                    .remove()
                    .end();
                 $('#subcauses').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing and why and how it works?