# changing input text field into a drop down when an option is selected from another drop down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, populate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First drop down menu to auto change the options of a second dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown)

this is for my view entries (search) page. the page displays one input field and a drop down list contaning ID, category, Title. my problem is when i select the category option, the input field must be changed into a drop down containing the different categories. help?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is your answer. Using jQuery or pure javascript Ajax is your choice. Giving you the full code is quite an ask. A simple search on Google will give you tons of tutorials. My recommendation - Go for jQuery + Ajax since it reduces the effort a lot

UPDATE:

Create a div and give it an id of `result`. Put your textbox (which you want to change into dropdown) in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('select[name="put select tag name here"]').change(function(){

        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value == 'Category')
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'getCatgories.php',
                data:'cat='+value,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('div#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});

</script>
```

In your `getCategories.php` file, get the category by `$cat = $_POST['cat'];` and then use $cat to fetch results from database and populate it in a `select` tag.

Comment: the only problem is i dont know jq or ajax. total noob.