# Multiple dynamic combobox javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, combobox

Is there a chance to have a combobox, which every time I select something in there, it opens a new one, etc, until no more data to select?

(options must not be repeated)

Combo1 - (opt1-opt2-opt3) - selected opt1
Combo2 - (opt2-opt3) - selected opt3
Combo3 - (opt2)

Comboboxes should be populated by querys using php and mysql.

How can I do it ?
Cheers!

Comment: check out this [link](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php)

Comment: and another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown)

Comment: @NikosTsirakis, first dont work

Comment: Try to create a sample code and give us your try here and we can assist you further if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some jquery that will do this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
    <option></option>
    <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
    <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('body').append(newComboBox);
        }
    }
});​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/)**

**Explanation**

```
// Adds an event listener to each combo box that is created dynmically
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    // Gets this selected value
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    // Checks if there are enough options left to create another combo box
    if (selectedValue !== '' && $(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        // Clones the just selected combo box and get the current and next combo index
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        // Removes any "children" combo boxes
        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        // Checks if a blank value is not selected to create another combo box
        if (selectedValue !== '' && $(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
            // Gives this new combo box the correct id, index, parent class
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);

            // Removes the selected option from the new combo box
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();

            // Adds the combo box to the page. Disco!
            $('body').append(newComboBox);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @3dgoo, im seeing your example, but when user deselect a combobox it stays blank and should disappear right?

Comment: @user1148875 - Yeah you are right. I missed this bug. I've fixed this up now and updated the code. Good pick up. Thanks.