# How to populate a drop down based on previous drop down selection SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have been following This solution[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown) to create a drop down list the changes based on the users previous selection in another dropdown higher in the page. However I was unsure what I need to do at the  Options would have been initially populated here

**Thanks**

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost');
mysql_select_db("test");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = 0");
echo "<select name='name'>";
while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
    echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>

        <select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
        <!-- Options would have been initially populated here -->
            </select>
        <select id="sub">    
            </select>

   <script type="text/javascript"> function ajaxfunction(parent)
{
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php?parent=' + parent;
    success: function(data) {
        $('#sub option').remove();  //// here sub is the id of second select box
        $('#sub').append(data)
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Im probably missing something silly but right now I can figure it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
**<select onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
**<!-- Options would have been initially populated here -->**
</select>**


<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxfunction(parent)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php?parent=' + parent;
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sub option').remove();  //// here sub is the id of second select box
            $('#sub').append(data)
        }
    });
}
</script>
/// script section may be any where on your page


<select id="sub">    ////second select box
</select>
```

Comment: I need to put the code below into the *** part I think? but I cant get it to work....... $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = 0");
while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
    echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>

Comment: Do I have to have something in the <!-- Options would be populated here??? I feel like the initial Select would have to go there? but I cannot get that to work. It obviously populates the first dropdown list that's easy, but once I put it into the select onchange, it just displays the options as text, rather than a list drop down

Comment: here <!-- Options would   there will be the options fro the first select box.

Comment: How do I get this code to work there? do I need to add extra quotations etc?...........................................  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE `parent` = 0");
while(($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
    echo '<option value="', $data['id'],'">', $data['name'],'</option>'
?>

Comment: I edited the post to contain my code, what I mean is I think I need to move the php at the top into the <!-- Options would be populated here. At the moment, I get the first box populated from my DB, however the second drop down displays nothing. But I think that is due to the location of the first box? @Goutam Pal