# generating the second drop down list depending on the first list value

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I need two drop down list in the same page.The values in the first list are to be fetched from one table and depending on that selected value  another set of values should be fetched from another table and show it in the second list.After that both the selected values are to be inserted in a third table on a button click.
Please help me out.

Comment: You should use Ajax for it..  Example [link](http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t)

Comment: try this script http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5988-PHP-Retrieve-MySQL-query-results-into-arrays.html

Comment: follow link 
here is solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You should add onchange event for the first element and in the onchange handler call an ajax call. In the success handler populate the second dropdown element.