# Auto Load Second Dropdown using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Im having a problem loading the `AJAX` and I tried to follow this answer by `Praveen Kumar`
 [First drop down menu to auto change the options of a second dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown)
and also read about ajax from http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and it is quoted there

> Since Version 2.8, The javascript global variable ajaxurl can be used
>   in case you want to separate your javascript code from php files into
>   javascript only files. This is true on the administration side only.

So i guess there is no problem loading ajax in my page. My code goes like this

**HTML:**

```
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    <select name="region" onchange="messi_code(this.value)">
        <option>Region Select</option>
        <option value="East">East</option>
        <option value="West">West</option>
        <option value="North">North</option>
            <option value="South">South</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="region_branch" name="region_branch">
        <option>Select City</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function  messi_code(parent){
     url= 'process.php?parent=' + parent,
     $.get(url,function(data){
       alert(data);
     /* $("#region_branch").html(data);*/
    });
}
</script>
```

by the way, in the ajax script I tried `POST`, `GET` and remove the `type` and still having an error in the J-console, error says `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxfunction is not defined: onchange`

would appreciate some help in this.

Comment: My guess is that this is likely a scoping issue.  If you add this line right before the function declaration what happens?  $(function(){
 $('select[name="region"]').on('change', function(){ajaxfunction($('select[name="region"]').val())})
};)

Comment: How are you calling this `ajaxfunction()` ? Also you need to put a comma  instead of semi-colon at `..parent=' + parent,` `..$("#region_branch").html(data);
            },`  `..type:'POST',`

Comment: @user007 im calling the `ajaxfunction()` in the parent dropdown menu and trigger it on `onchange event`. and I changed the semi-colons to commas as you said but im having an error which is `cannot call method ajax or undefined.`

Comment: Try changing your `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @joe42 it says undefined function.

Comment: @user007 i change the code which `messi fan` provided and the error now is cannot call method GET or if i changed it to POST then its cannot call method POST. and i trid to change the commas and semi-colon too.

Comment: Did you change the `<script>` tag too? It gave me an `undefined` error when I didn't have the `<script>` tag replaced like above.

Comment: yes i did. i tried both too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <select name="region" onchange="messi_fan(this.value);">
        <option>Region Select</option>

        <option value="East">East</option>
        <option value="West">West</option>
        <option value="North">North</option>
            <option value="South">South</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="region_branch" name="region_branch">
        <option>Select City</option>
    </select>

</form>


<script>
     function  messi_fan(parent){
     url= 'process.php?parent=' + parent;
     $.post(url,function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aJcj/)

Comment: im kinda having an exception and it says `cannot call method POST` and if its on GET then `cannot call method GET`. and i tried the jfiddle you provided and it works there.

Comment: please try to change jquery version. im using jquery 1.7 in fiddle

Comment: sorry but im trying to include this code into wordpress which is running on 1.10.2, im still trying to work on some other method too.