# Mapping values in dropdown 2 dependent on value selected in dropdwon 1 via php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am fresher in php & mysql.
I have a from where there are 2 dropdwon's. The value in dropdwon are coming via mysql. But now i am not able to get the value in 2nd dropdown dependent on value selected in 1st dropdown. 
Here is the code i have tried so far.

Please Help!

Thank You

```
<html>
<head><title>Sheet</title></head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">SKU Selection</h2>
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$db="sample";
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT(Site) FROM `bom`";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "Site Name :";
echo "<select name='Site'>";
echo "<option value='0'>Select Site</option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['Site']."'>".$row['Site']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$sql1="SELECT BOM Desc FROM `bom` where Site= ";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
 echo "<br>";
echo "SKU :";
echo "<select name='SKU'>";
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo "<option value='".$row1['BOM Desc']."'>".$row1['BOM Desc']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "SELECT BOM Desc FROM `bom` where Site= "; ? have syntax error. why site = null ?

Comment: Dats where the issue is i dnt knw wot to code there. Here is where i want to get the value of the selected value from dropdwon 1

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function - and dependent drop downs are widely discussed

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your fixed code here:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Sheet</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2 align="center">SKU Selection</h2>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        $db = "sample";
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(Site) FROM `bom`";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // add error show info
        echo "Site Name :";
        echo "<select name='Site'>";
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Site</option>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['Site'] . "'>" . $row['Site'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        $sql1 = "SELECT BOM Desc FROM `bom` where Site IS NULL "; // change the for null site
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // add error show info
        echo "<br>";
        echo "SKU :";
        echo "<select name='SKU'>";
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row1['BOM Desc'] . "'>" . $row1['BOM Desc'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you need load on second select php only cant handle this because you must give time to user for check first select.

I think the better way is using Ajax request for second:

[Auto Load Second Dropdown using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422949/auto-load-second-dropdown-using-ajax)

Comment: Thank You ! Will check this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use in both <*select*> the clause **selected** to show the selected <*option*>.
Then, in the first <*select*> add the *on change* event to launch a page refresh so that:

- The selected entry is recognised as selected
- The SQL for the second drop-down can be filtered on the selected entry in first dropdown

The first select should appear then like this:

```
<select onChange='if(options[selectedIndex].value) { location=options[selectedIndex].value;}' size='1'>
<option value='?site=Plant1'>Plant ONE</option>
<option value='?site=Plant2' selected>Plant 2</option>
</select>
```

When Plant 2 is selected, the page will be refreshed with the URL containing the parameter **&site=Plant2** which you can read in the variable **$_REQUEST['site']** to be used in the 2nd SQL query