# How to show the subcategories which belong to a category?

Tags: php

This code is for both category and subcategory.In category i am showing the all the value in dropdown but for subcategory i want to show the exact subcategories which are belongs to a category .please help me

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category Name</label>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option>Select Category</option>  
        <?php 
            $res= mysql_query("select * from ".CATEGORY."  order by id asc");
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Subcategory Name</label>
    <select name="type1" id="type1">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <?php $res= mysql_query("select * from ".SUBCATEGORY." order by id asc"); 
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['sub_name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Ajax to fetch sub-categories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In it using jquery when a category is selected it will take value and from ajax value is posted to your ajax.php file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category Name</label>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option>Select Category</option>  
        <?php 
            $res= mysql_query("select * from ".CATEGORY."  order by id asc");
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Subcategory Name</label>
    <select name="type1" id="type1">


    </select>
</div> 


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#type').on("change",function () {
        var categoryId = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "categoryId="+categoryId,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#type1").html(response);
            },
        });
    }); 

});

</script>
```

make a php file name it ajax.php in same directory

and put this code

```
<?php 
$categoryId = $_POST['categoryId'];
echo "<option>Select Category</option>";
$res= mysql_query("select * from ".SUBCATEGORY." WHERE category_id = $categoryId order by id asc"); 
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        echo "<option value='".$data['id']."'>."$data['sub_name']."</option>";
        }
?>
```

this will work

Comment: Thank you very much .it realy works and help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong remove the quete from the table name

```
$res= mysql_query("select * from ".CATEGORY."  order by id asc");
 $res= mysql_query("select * from ".SUBCATEGORY." order by id asc");
```

like this

```
$res= mysql_query("select * from CATEGORY  order by id asc");
 $res= mysql_query("select * from SUBCATEGORY order by id asc");
```

and in my view you might have to add where clause in your second query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform AJAX request onCategoryClick or generate java code with arrays of subcategories which belongs to category and switch between them in js.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238038/3711660 - about AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

Try This May Help You...

```
<?php
if($_GET['id'])
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}
?>                          
<script>
function newDoc(str) 
{
    window.location.assign("your_page_name.php?id="+str)
}
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category Name</label>
  <select name="type" id="type" onchange="newDoc(this.value)">
       <option>Select Category</option>  

        <?php 
        $res= mysql_query("select * from ".CATEGORY."  order by id asc");

        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['cat_name'];?></option>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>

    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Subcategory Name</label>
    <select name="type1" id="type1">
        <option>Select Category</option>
         <?php 
         $res= mysql_query("select * from ".SUBCATEGORY." where SUB_ID='$id' order by id asc"); 
         while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
         {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><?php echo $data['sub_name'];?></option>
         <?php 
         } 
         ?>
    </select>
</div>
```