# Unable to dynamically populate dropdown with states from a country select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make a dynamic dropdown when you select country, the state populates.
I have all the information stored in two tables.
How exactly do I do this?  I have no problems doing the initial country list.

But for states, I don't know how to handle javascript since that is client side and PHP is server side so the PHP would be executed before I get the countryID from the dropdown.
Since I don't know how to code time travel, and I know I have seen this sort of thing before, how do I accomplish this?

And I rather not download/pull all the data into an array since that is a total waste of memory so I figured a little sql, php, and javascript would work, but I am definitely missing something.

Removed original source as it is now below.

The database schema and information is below, if interested:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_earth |
+-----------------+
| regions         |
| subregions      |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> desc regions;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country       | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| continent     | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| currency_code | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| currency_name | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_prefix  | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc subregions;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| region_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timezone  | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,country from regions order by country desc limit 15;
+-----+--------------------------------------+
| id  | country                              |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
| 716 | Zimbabwe                             |
| 894 | Zambia                               |
| 887 | Yemen                                |
| 732 | Western Sahara                       |
| 876 | Wallis and Futuna                    |
| 704 | Vietnam                              |
| 862 | Venezuela                            |
| 336 | Vatican                              |
| 548 | Vanuatu                              |
| 860 | Uzbekistan                           |
| 858 | Uruguay                              |
| 581 | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| 840 | United States                        |
| 826 | United Kingdom                       |
| 784 | United Arab Emirates                 |
+-----+--------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, name from subregions where region_id=840 limit 5;
+------+------------+
| id   | name       |
+------+------------+
| 3680 | Alaska     |
| 3681 | Alabama    |
| 3682 | Arkansas   |
| 3683 | Arizona    |
| 3684 | California |
+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.52 sec)
```

A lot of snipped code, but this is the full(ish) src for index.php.  generate.php takes the values and does things with the data.

```
<!-- snip -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function show(id)
{
   if ( id == "v7" )
   {
      document.getElementById('v8').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('v7').style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById('v7').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('v8').style.visibility = 'visible';
   }

}

function enable()
{
    var value = document.getElementById("country").selectedIndex;
    if ( value > 0 )
    {
       document.getElementById("state").disabled = false;
    }
    else
       document.getElementById("state").disabled = true;
}

function getCountry()
{
   var e = document.getElementById("country");
   var countryID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
//   alert( "Selected Country: " + country + "(" + countryID + ") ");
   return countryID;
}

function getStates()
{
    $('#state').html('');
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var countryID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index1.php",
            data: {countryID:countryID},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result){
                var toAppend = '';
                $.each(data,function(i,o){
                    toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';
                });

                $('#state').append(toAppend);       
            },  
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- major league snip -->
<div class="formDiv">
<form id="frmSigGen" name="frmSigGen" method="post" action="generate.php" class="form">
  <table border="0" align="center" class="SmTable">
      <tr>
      <td class="td"><div align="right">State/Provence:</div></td>
      <td class="td"><label>
        <select name="state" class="dropdown" id="state" disabled="disabled" onchange="getStates();">
        <option value="">State/Provence</option>
   <?php
      $countryID=$_POST['countryID'];
      $query = "select id, name from subregions where region_id=".$countryID;
      $reuslt=RunQuery($query);
      echo json_encode($reuslt);
   ?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="td"><div align="right">Country:</div></td>
        <td class="td"><label>
          <select name="country" class="dropdown" id="country" onchange="enable();">
          <option value="">Select Country</option>
          <?php 
             $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password'); 
             if (!$con) 
             {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
             }

             mysql_select_db('earth');
             $query = "select id,country from regions order by country";
             $result = mysql_query($query);

//           while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
         while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) )              
         { 
          ?>
             <option value=<?php echo $row->id; ?>><?php echo $row->country;?></option>
          <?php } 
              mysql_free_result($result);
          ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: Can you figure it out from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown

Comment: I am having issues with the ajaxy/jquery part here: `data: {country:country},`.  It seems in the firefox dev console it fails (data not defined)

Comment: Can you show the code that's producing the error?

Comment: It is that getStates function that @ashkufaraz posted below.  Soon as I change the dropdown for country, the dev console shows the error that data is not defined.  `$.each(data,function(i,o){`

Comment: Change `success: function(result){` to `success: function(data){`. Notice I changed *result* to *data*.

Comment: I think adding `toAppend += '<option value=' +o.id + '>' + o.name + '</option>';` works but i dont know why the value isn't passing and when i view source code, the dropdown seems blank but i assume it'll still post?  is this even correct?

Comment: Are you saying the second dropdown loads the states just fine in the browser, but when you view source code you're not seeing the states loaded? If so, that's normal. View Source typically shows you the original page load. If you want to see the dynamically added source code right mouse clck and select *inspect element*.

Comment: Never mind I put the wrong data element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

like this

```
function getStates()
{
    $('#state').html('');
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
    var countryID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getStates.php",
            data: {countryID:countryID},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result){
                var toAppend = '';
                $.each(data,function(i,o){
                    toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';
                });

                $('#state').append(toAppend);       
            },  
    });
}
```

getStates PHP

```
   $countryID=$_POST['countryID'];
   $query = "select id, name from subregions where region_id=".$countryID;
   $reuslt=RunQuery($query);
   echo json_encode($reuslt);
```

Comment: Ah I had a feeling AJAX had to be used.  Never used it before.  Last time I did a dynamic form was in a C# Winform and didn't recall it being that overly complicated.  Let me try this out and if I get into any trouble I will report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I screwed something up.  This form is all in one page right now, foo1.php for example.  The data in the form doesn't get inserted into a database.  It is an emailer for internal purposes essentially.  So I I put the php code in between the selects like how I did for country, and updated the getstate js code in the header.  tho, the HTML only goes upto the state part now, since the country selecter is what unlocks the state, nothing seems to work. I also updated the url to the same url as the file itself.  I hope I was clear since comments limit the space and formatting code is awkward.

Comment: i do not understand! create new question and set code.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function RunQuery() is what I get.  I think I modified the getStates.php correct with the connection calls (so the rest of the form now loads again) but the states dont populate.  Also, what do I put in the onchange on country select?  Anything in state onchange?  Because i disable state until country is selected to prevent SQL error.

Comment: RunQuery(); is sample function.in country onchage must call getStates();

Comment: Hi, I am adding one more comment/question since it is related.  Form Reset won't reset the dynamic portion.  I made a resetForm() function with `$('#frmSigGen')[0].reset();` and an onClick member that calls it on the reset button but it doesnt work.  Anything else I need to be aware of on reset, since the state list will still show from the last selected country.