# How to call 2 related tables in a single query from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am new to database programming. I want know how to call two tables on a single form.

For example, I have 2 tables called "Car Brand" and "Car Model". Whenever a user chooses a car brand (e.g BMW) from the combo box, the other combo box should list out all models of BMWs from the "Car Model" table.

Should I use ajax for that and if so, how do I do it? it's really hard for me to search for this solution online since I'm not very familiar with this area.

Hope to learn how through this question.
Thanks

BTW, I'm using PHP.

Comment: Add the code you tried, so we can help you to short out the problems. And add you table structure too....

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: You may use AJAX but you don't need to. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: #NoOffense, kindly do some homework and comeback if you are stuck.

Comment: @KenZo Miyazawa: is this what you are looking for? Check my answer Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explain this using taken two drop down as HTML data driven by *jQuery AJAX* from *MySql* tables.

*For example*, we have two dropdown for listing "*Car Brand*" and "*Car Model*". On changing "Car Brand" dorpdown values, the corresponding "*Car Model*" dropdown values will be loaded dynamically using *jQuery AJAX*.

**1) HTML**: This code contains HTML code for "*Car Brand*", "*Car Model*" dropdown.

```
<div class="frmDronpDown">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Car Brand:</label><br/>
        <select name="brand" id="brand-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Car Brand</option>
        <?php
        foreach($results as $brand) {
            ?><option value="<?php echo $brand["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $brand["name"]; ?></option><?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Car Model:</label><br/>
        <select name="model" id="model-list" class="demoInputBox">
        <option value="">Select Car Model</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2) JQuery AJAX**: 
This script contains function that will be called on changing *Car Brand* dropdown values. It will send AJAX request to a *PHP* page to get corresponding *Car Model* dropdown options.

```
<script>
    function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_model.php",
        data:'brand_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#model-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**3) PHP**: This PHP code connects database to retrieve model table values based on the brand id passed by jQuery AJAX call.

```
<?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");//Your connection...
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    if(!empty($_POST["brand_id"])) {
        $query ="SELECT * FROM model WHERE brandID = '" . $_POST["brand_id"] . "'";
        $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);

        ?><option value="">Select Car Model</option><?php
        foreach($results as $model) {
            ?><option value="<?php echo $model["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $model["name"]; ?></option><?php
        }
    }
?>
```

After above three steps, you can see two drop down call "*Car Brand*" and "*Car Model*". See result by select available car brand from "*Car Brand*" dropdown.

Hope this help you well!

Comment: I successfully done with the codes but I am using different source code by using JavaScript instead of JQuery as you post.. should i post my codes here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax functionality for this.
Use jquery onchange event to get the Brand from first dropdown and send GET request to fetch all the related models from database using ajax. When you get the list of models from database, simply populate it in dropdown.

You can check this: [First drop down menu to auto change the options of a second dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237900/first-drop-down-menu-to-auto-change-the-options-of-a-second-dropdown)