# How can I optimise my JavaScript and cut down on the amount of "$.fn.not(...)" calls I make?

Tags: jquery

I've got a JavaScript file in which I call the `$.fn.not(...);` function at least a dozen times.
How can I optimise my code and prevent multiple calls of the same function for the same reason?

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ba = ".form_elem_program option[value='Business Administration']";
  var cjc = ".form_elem_program option[value='Criminal Justice: Corrections']";
  var cm = ".form_elem_program option[value='Construction Management']";
  var da = ".form_elem_program option[value='Dental Assisting']";
  var dh = ".form_elem_program option[value='Dental Hygiene']";
  var dms = ".form_elem_program option[value='Diagnostic Medical Sonography']";
  var ma = ".form_elem_program option[value='Medical Assisting']";
  var mo = ".form_elem_program option[value='Medical Office']";
  var pt = ".form_elem_program option[value='Pharmacy Technology']";
  var rt = ".form_elem_program option[value='Respiratory Therapy']";
  var rn = ".form_elem_program option[value='Registered Nursing']";
  var st = ".form_elem_program option[value='Surgical Technology']";
  var vt = ".form_elem_program option[value='Veterinary Technology']";
  var vn = ".form_elem_program option[value='Vocational Nursing']";
  var amt = ".form_elem_program option[value='Aviation Maintenance Technology']";
  var et = ".form_elem_program option[value='Electrical Technology']";
  var hvac = ".form_elem_program option[value='Heating, Ventilation, Air Conditioning - Refrigeration Technology']";
  var imt = ".form_elem_program option[value='Industrial Maintenance Technology']";
  if (campus == "visalia") {
    // XXX: this is the "problem code":
    $('#program').children().not(":first").not(ba).not(cjc).not(da).not(dh).not(ma).not(mo).not(pt).not(rt).not(rn).not(vn).not(hvac).not(imt).remove();
  }
  if (campus == "porterville") {
    // XXX: this is the "problem code":
    $('#program').children().not(":first").not(ba).not(ma).not(mo).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the element inclusively instead of exclusively?

Comment: the .not() method will actually take an array of selectors, if that helps :)

Comment: Use a class on the `option` elements instead.

Comment: What @J.Chen is suggesting would look like: `$('#program').children().not([ba,cjc,cm,da,dh,dms,ma,mo,pt,rt,rn,st,vt,vn,amt,et,hvac,imt,].join(','))` This is still crazy though, group your `option` elements by class name logically so you can do `$('#program .form_elem_program option:not(.visalia.school-program):')` or whatever.

Comment: Or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11238154/451969).

Comment: Phillip, I see you're a new user. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks everyone! The form is controlled by a third party so I can't add classes per school. The array of selectors looks like exactly what I need. I tried comma separated selectors and it didn't work, but this is worth a shot!

Comment: The array of selectors didn't work. Ended up using forEach() instead.

Comment: @PhillipBarnes I'm glad you found your solution but, please remember that `Array.prototype.forEach()` doesn't work in every browser, that's why I've used `$.each()` in my answer. Although you could alternatively use a JavaScript for loop.

Comment: @PhillipBarnes Also when an answer works for you, you're supposed to click the little *"tick"* underneath it to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a code review of working code, it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your script by generating the required selector using an array of the option values to ignore.
Meaning that; instead of literally repeating the same string & calling the same function over and over again you only call the `$.fn.not(...);` function once using a single selector that's been created on the fly.
This makes sure your JS isn't bogged down and that your site's performance isn't affected by dozens repeats of the same string and / or calls of the function.

Here is your simplified code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // create the selectors
  var cs = function(group) {
    // prepare the result string
    var result = "";
    // loop through the option value groups
    for(var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
      result += ".form_elem_program option[value='" + group[i] + "'],";
    }
    // return the generated selector
    return result;
  };

  // handle the first selector group
  if(campus == "visalia") {
    $("#program").children().not(":first").not(cs([
      "Business Administration","Medical Assisting","Medical Office"
    ])).remove();
  }

  // handle the second selector group
  else if(campus == "porterville") {
    $("#program").children().not(":first").not(cs([
      "Business Administration", "Medical Assisting", "Medical Office", "Criminal Justice: Corrections",
      "Construction Management", "Dental Assisting", "Dental Hygiene", "Diagnostic Medical Sonography",
      "Pharmacy Technology", "Respiratory Therapy", "Registered Nursing", "Surgical Technology",
      "Veterinary Technology", "Vocational Nursing", "Aviation Maintenance Technology", "Electrical Technology",
      "Heating, Ventilation, Air Conditioning - Refrigeration Technology", "Industrial Maintenance Technology",
    ])).remove();
  }
});
```

An alternative way would be to use a function to inject each option value into the selector string then use `$.each(..., ...);` to ignore each *not* selector, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // generate a new selector
  var cs2 = function(value) {
    return ".form_elem_program option[value='" + value + "']";
  };
  // create the required selectors
  var ba = cs2("Business Administration"),
    cjc = cs2("Criminal Justice: Corrections"),
    cm = cs2("Construction Management"),
    da = cs2("Dental Assisting"),
    dh = cs2("Dental Hygiene"),
    dms = cs2("Diagnostic Medical Sonography"),
    ma = cs2("Medical Assisting"),
    mo = cs2("Medical Office"),
    pt = cs2("Pharmacy Technology"),
    rt = cs2("Respiratory Therapy"),
    rn = cs2("Registered Nursing"),
    st = cs2("Surgical Technology"),
    vt = cs2("Veterinary Technology"),
    vn = cs2("Vocational Nursing"),
    amt = cs2("Aviation Maintenance Technology"),
    et = cs2("Electrical Technology"),
    hvac = cs2("Heating, Ventilation, Air Conditioning - Refrigeration Technology"),
    imt = cs2("Industrial Maintenance Technology");

  // get the elements
  var elements = $("#program").children().not(":first");

  // handle the first selector group
  if (campus == "visalia") {
    $.each([ba, cjc, da, dh, ma, mo, pt, rt, rn, v, hvac, imt], function(i, element) {
      elements = elements.not(element);
    });
  }

  // handle the second selector group
  else if (campus == "porterville") {
    $.each([ba, ma, mo], function(i, element) {
      elements = elements.not(element);
    });
  }
});
```

Good luck and all the best!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it would be:

```
var elems = $('#program').children().not(":first");
if (campus == "visalia") {
  [ba, cjc, da, dh, ma, mo, pt, rt, rn, v, hvac, imt].forEach(function(e) {
    elems = elems.not(e);
  });
}
if (campus == "porterville") {
  [ba, ma, mo].forEach(function(e) {
    elems = elems.not(e);
  });
}
elems.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this code and took it a step farther. I put all the campus / program pairs into an object, then rather than run through a bunch of if statements, I simply called the object property I wanted.

Comment: I also took @Mango suggestion and used jQuery's `$.each()` to keep support for old IE.

Answer (score 0):

I took suggestions in answers from @Mango and @Isac, then ended up with the following code. I needed to use `$.each()` method to run through all the `$.not()` methods.

This allowed me to use arrays and objects to further simplify the code. Our program and campus mix is constantly changing, so maintainability is crucial for this code.

```
// generate a new selector
var fieldOption = function(value) {
  return ".form_elem_program option[value='" + value + "']";
};
// create the required selectors for each program
var ba   = fieldOption("Business Administration"),
    cjc  = fieldOption("Criminal Justice: Corrections"),
    // there are more programs not included for simplicity of answer
    imt  = fieldOption("Industrial Maintenance Technology"),
    it   = fieldOption("Information Technology");

// create object with array of selectors of the campus programs
var campusPrograms = {
  visalia:          [ba, cjc, da, dh, ma, mo, pt, rt, rn, vn, hvac, imt],
  hanford:          [ba, ma, mo],
  // there are more campuses not included for simplicity of answer
  delano:           [ba, ma, mo],
  porterville:      [ba, ma, mo]
};

// run function to pull campus param from URL
var campusURL = getUrlParams()['campus'];
// get array from campusPrograms object
var programs = campusPrograms[campusURL];

// remove all programs except ones included in campus array
var elems = $('#program').children().not(":first");  

$.each(programs, function(index, value) {
  elems = elems.not(value);
});

elems.remove();
```

Comment: Phillip, I've used dirtymarkup.com to tidy the code, alternatively you could install JSHint in the Atom / Sublime text editors to make sure the code you write is free of errors and warnings.